How to capture user analytics for multiple domains using AWS RUM?
I have a single backend and frontend application connected to three different domain names (e.g., domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com). All traffic is routed to a single server, with the domains being the only difference.
I want to capture user analytics using AWS Real User Monitoring (RUM) for all three domains. However, AWS RUM seems to only allow data collection for one domain at a time.
Is it possible to configure AWS RUM to collect data from multiple domains?
Are there any specific settings or permissions I need to adjust to make this work?
